# Dynamic Data For core plot pie chart

Tags: swift, xcode7, core-plot

Im wanting to code this core plot pie chart so that the two data points are dynamic and come from 2 uilabels. chart needs to redraw every time that a value is changed.

ignore the var dataForChart i just used it to test the chart which is working fine

Thank you!

var dataForChart = [50, 40]

```
// MARK: - Plot Data Source Methods


    func numberOfRecordsForPlot(plot: CPTPlot) -> UInt{
    return 2
}


func numberForPlot(plot: CPTPlot, field: UInt, recordIndex: UInt) -> AnyObject?{
    if Int(recordIndex) > self.dataForChart.count {
        return nil
    }
    else {
        switch CPTPieChartField(rawValue: Int(field))! {
        case .SliceWidth:
            return (self.dataForChart)[Int(recordIndex)] as NSNumber

        default:
            return recordIndex as NSNumber
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Call `reloadData()` on the plot any time the input data changes. The plot will load new data from `numberForPlot()` and redraw itself.